# How to pronounce $ in linux?

Tags: bash

How would one read things like these in linux : $, $*, $?, $#, $@ ?

Is there any convention that people follow while talking/explaining about these things?

Thanks

Comment: There is a quite good video explaining it. Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IfHm6R5le0 ;)

Comment: The comment you posted is completely irrelevant to what I asked actually.

Comment: To add to the other answers here: the `$` in a terminal (indicating that it's ready for user input) might be called a *command prompt* or *shell prompt*. A `#` might be called a root shell prompt*.

Comment: https://www.prepressure.com/fonts/basics/character-names

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "$" character is commonly referred to as the "dollar sign". I would pronounce each character of the variable name as follows:

- `$` - dollar sign
- `*` - asterisk
- `?` - question mark
- `#` - pound (sign) or hash (symbol)
- `@` - at (symbol)

Occasionally, certain combinations have shortened forms. The opening characters of an executable script (`#!`) are pronounced as "shebang" or "hash bang". I'm not aware of shortened forms for any of your examples.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but in British English, it would be really confusing to call `#` pound... I call it 'hash'...

Comment: @Zanna good catch. I'll add that in.

Comment: Also, Perl is n̶o̶t̶o̶r̶i̶o̶u̶s̶ well known for giving weird names to variables and operators. For example, `<=>` is known as the spaceship operator.

Comment: That is clearly a spaceship. I don't see why you find it odd ;)

Comment: @NathanOsman `#` has to be `hash` in the Linux world. Otherwise, how would we have the hashbang?

Comment: Is it my EE sense of humor, or is stuff like "`$` - dollar sign" just slightly surreal for Ask Ubuntu? (Not saying it's wrong, just funny!)

Comment: My guess would be that prophets Ritchie and Thompson didn't choose dollar sign randomly. Since it has characteristic S shape and commonly used for shell variables, it probably originally was chosen to designate relationship with shell, at the time Bourne shell. But as with many things, over time original meaning is lost. I will have to look at my  System V book, maybe it will shed some light

Answer (score 10):

In my experience among Linuxers verbalising orally, **there is no universal fixed convention** attached to the pronunciation of these symbols.

They are called by the locally applicable name for the symbol itself [as suggested by Nathan Osman](https://askubuntu.com/a/815673/527764), or sometimes by what they do as operators in maths or in bash - whatever the speaker thinks will be understood by the listeners.

`$` seems to always be "dollar" or "dollar sign"

But `*` might be "asterisk" "star" or "glob"

`#` is "hash" (as in hashtag) in British English, "pound" in US English, or possibly "number sign" as in #1 #2 #3 in either, but sometimes I hear it called "comment sign"

It's much easier to explain code by writing it down. Talking about it usually ends in a lot of gesturing and sooner or later resorting to scribbling on beermats...

Comment: So `$` doesn't mean _cash_ and `$$` _more cash_? Also, I always thought `#` is called _the miniscule tic-tac-toe sign_. Dammit — I was wrong for years!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are pretty good. But I sould like to add that the $ is also commonly called "string" as it is often asociated with a string.

Also, I have heard ! called "bang" and * called "splat".

In addition, I have heard ^ called "carrot".

Comment: `^` is [*caret*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret), not carrot.